# using javascript function to initialize php variable

Tags: php, javascript

hi i want to initialize php variable in javascript function and than call the php function with php initialized variable. Please help me for solving this problem...

```
    <?php
    function printDiv($abc) {
        echo '<div align="center" width="100%"> ' . $abc . ' </div>';
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callPhpFunction(jsabc) {
            <?php $abc ?> = jsabc;
            document.write("<?php printDiv($abc) ?>");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You do realize that PHP and Javascript are two completely different languages, interpreted on different hosts, at different times?  Don't you ;)?

Comment: That's not how it works. Read some of the **Related** questions on the right to understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: PS: Don't use document.write().  It isn't doing anything for you here anyway.  But find a good JQuery tutorial and learn some 21st Century Javascript, OK? ;)

Comment: thank you for ur valuable comments

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it cannot be done the way you are describing. Javascript is a client side scripting and PHP is a server side scripting language. You will need to look into ajax calls to fill the javascript variables.

Order of Operations (bare-bones):

1. Server gets request for page
2. Server parses PHP, or other language, to send page to browser
3. Client recieves page from server
4. Loads any additional files/scripts needed - Restarts at step 1 for any new requests
5. Executes Javascript (Normally as it is loaded unless using jQuery $().ready then after document has loaded.